# WoD: Assault on XXX Apexis Crystal events

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have been doing the Apexis Crystal daily, but when I began questing in Draenor I would have the percentage bar appear in the assault areas (when not on the daily or the campaign quest).  In fact I was able to complete multiple in the same day if I ended up in the right area.  Even now I can occasionally complete more areas than just the daily I selected.

Is this a bug (which I hope sticks around lol), or is there another mechanism for when you can 'assault' an area, ie. weekly?  Or maybe just the first time you enter an area it shows up, then after only if on the daily?

Being able to complete the event while on a campaign quest (as per answer below) makes sense, but have also noticed it when I am not doing a campaign.

Comment: I noticed this as well. It seems that you can do one or two random sites once in a while. It is definitely not linked to the garrison quests, because I have done them all. So far there is no blue post to be found addressing this.

Answer (score 2):

When you are on a weekly garrison campaign quest (see this [achievement](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=9492) for a list) that takes place in one of the zones from the apexis crystal dailies you can do the assault for the apexis crystals parallel to your quest.

Comment: That does make sense, but I was also noticing it in zones away from the campaign quest, eg. daily is in Nagrand, but was able to do the Shadowmoon area (without having a campaign quest) ... edited the question